# C# dynamically shorten interval of Timer

Tags: c#, timer

Still getting my head wrapped around Timers in C# which are a LOT more powerful than in AS3.
I need to call another method at shorter and shorter intervals. Say once a second in the beginning, then gradually shorter intervals until maybe I am calling the method 100X a second.
I've used coroutines but pretty sure I need an actual Timer object. Can anyone help or point in the right direction?

Comment: Show us what you got so far

Comment: IMHO, You could also use a `Task` or a thread and have a `Thread.Sleep()` inside of the task/thread which gradually sleeps shorter and shorter durations. The advantage being that you can drop the code ceremony surrounding a timer and the timer callback.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with this example:

```
System.Timers.Timer t = new System.Timers.Timer();

    public void TimerSetup()
    {
        t.Interval = 1000;
        t.Elapsed += ElapsedMethod;
        t.Start();
    }

    public void ElapsedMethod(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        //do stuff
        t.Interval = t.Interval - 5; //however much you want it to reduce.
    }
```

You will have to determine the conditions that you need for reducing the timer interval, and when to do it, but this should give you a start.

Comment: thanks. Isn't it necessary to stop the timer before changing the interval? and then restart it?

Comment: I don't believe so, but you can do a test to check

Answer (score 0):

Using a `Task`:

```
shouldIStayInThisLoop = true;
interval = 1000;  // 1000 milliseconds == 1 second
Task.Factory.StartNew(()->
{
    while (shouldIStayInThisLoop)
    {
        DoSomeStuff();

        if (SomeConditionIsMet())
        {
            interval = GetNewInterval();
        }

        Thread.Sleep(interval);

        shouldIStayInThisLoop = CheckIfIShouldStayInThisLoop();
    }   
});
```